# Indexing over 4 dimensions in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I am trying to index the maximum windspeed of each grid point at each timestep for a set of data I am working on. I have a variable `ws_interp` which is the windspeed profile with 4 dimensions (time, height, latitude, longitude). I want to index the maximum windspeed at each grid coordinate at each timestep with an index `ws_index`. I should therefore output a 3 dimensional array when I index `ws_interp` however I keep getting a 4 dimensional array the same size as `ws_interp`.

Here is a reproducible example of my problem:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5*3*2*1)
c = a.reshape((5,3,2,1))
ws_interp = xr.DataArray(c, dims=("time", "isosurf", "latitude", "longitude"))
ws_interp.shape

(5, 3, 2, 1)

b = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(10))
d = b.reshape((5,2,1))
ws_index = xr.DataArray(d,dims=("time", "latitude","longitude"))
ws_index.shape

(5, 2, 1)

ws_interp[ws_index].shape

(5, 2, 1, 3)
```

I don't understand why my indexed xarray is shape (5,2,1,3) when I want it to be (5,2,1) like the shape of the index array. It did what I wanted when the time dimension wasn't involved but now it doesn't seem to work. Any helped would be most appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, simply had to use

```
ws_interp.isel(isosurf = ws_index)
```

to index over a specific axis.